# Same dimensions across different pixel densities

Tags: cordova, phonegap, pixel-density

I am developing a Cordova app and I have this problem: I wrote all the css with px measures, now I see that in lower density devices everything appear a lot bigger.
I want everything to be the same dimensions on every device (even at the cost of having smaller texts in smaller devices), I tried using rem instead of px but it doesn't solve the problem.
I tried to use the zoom property but some elements are already at the right dimension and I don't wanna change them.
The perfect solution would be to "force" the density with viewport but the only attribute that did the trick is deprecated... :/

Comment: I have a landscape app, and used vw when defining font-size so that it would fit correctly based on the maximum width element - is this what you're looking to do?

Comment: Try adding the crosswalk webview. `cordova plugin add cordova-plugin-crosswalk-webview`. Note: It will increase your final APK size about 20MB.

Comment: I tried with Crosswalk but it changed nothing.
I used vw for every dimension and it worked. It's not exactly the same in every device but the texts are resized good and spaces too! Thank you so much :)